# QLineEdit input filtering

Tags: qt, validation, text, caret

ALL,

I'd like to know if it is possible to do an input filtering inside QLineEdit based on the caret position.

Meaning if I am at the position 0 I allow to enter digits only, but if I'm at the position 5 I allow only letters? This is just an example in the real application more sophisticated checks will be implemented.

Also, I don't want the RE solution - RE are slow to compile and work with. I want a native QT solution because the "mask" will depend on the user input.

Thank you.

P.S.: I can do it very easily with wxWidgets, but the current project I'm working with is written with Qt.

Answer (score 0):

[`QLineEdit`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html) has the function `setInputMask(QString &inputMask)` which should do what you want:

```
line.setInputMask(inputMask)
```

Comment: is it possible to change the mask dynamically, based on the first character (at position 0) typed?

Comment: @Igor I don't know. There's nothing about that in the docs. Maybe using a QValidator would be the solution

Comment: I'm looking for the control where I can switch between MGRS, UPS, Lat/Lon and other coordinate system on the fly based on the firsat character typed and some other condition. I also want the user to prevent typing wrong character at the position (s)he at. So getting the caret position and receiving the input character is the goal. I don't see how validator can play the role here.